# NodeMailer: Error: Connection timeout

Tags: email, nodemailer

I'm using NodeMailer to send emails. I've been successfully using my gmail account to send emails. I just switched to my domains custom email through Godaddy. This email runs through hotmail. Now that I've made this switch I get the Error: Connection timeout everytime. Gmail still works but I cannot get hotmail to work.

Any advice on how to fix this? Are there any better email choices to use for NodeMailer?

Here's my set up:

```
 var smtpTrans = nodemailer.createTransport({
       service: 'hotmail',
        auth: {
            user: 'contact@my-domain.com',
            pass: '*********'
        }
      });
      var mailOptions = {
        to: rental.createdbyemail,
        from: 'email',
        subject: 'Your apartment was just rented!',
        text: 'my email'  
      };
      smtpTrans.sendMail(mailOptions, function(err) {
        console.log('email sent')
        if (err){
        console.log(err)
        } else {
        // res.redirect('/')
        }
      });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing a bit of research looks like using a dedicated email system like SendGrid is the way to go. Check out this [guide](https://medium.com/code-well-live-forever/emails-with-nodemailer-sendgrid-c98cd37c8e03)

Code Setup:

```
// emailer.js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const sendgridTransport = require('nodemailer-sendgrid-transport');

// Configure Nodemailer SendGrid Transporter
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(
  sendgridTransport({
    auth: {
      api_user: process.env.SENDGRID_API_USER,    // SG username
      api_key: process.env.SENDGRID_API_PASSWORD, // SG password
    },
  })
);

// Create Email Options
const options = {
  to: <to_email@domain.com>,
  from: <from_email@domain.com>, // Totally up to you
  subject: <email_subject>,
  html: <html_body>,             // For sending HTML emails
};

// Send Email
transporter.sendEmail(options, (err, resp) => {
  if (err) {
    // handle error
  } else {
    // handle success
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey there I am having the same issue, but I don't understand why it would give a connection timeout if it's a cold IP issue. If send grid is a better trusted solution, then gmail would simply reject the email right? Why would it timeout?

Comment: @RakshithRavi Hey! I believe there is a timeout because it is attempting to connect to the mail server and taking too long to do so. (Just a guess.) I could not get it to work at all using my hotmail email address because it was not able to connect fast enough. The send grid email works outstandingly

Comment: Well, I cannot accept that SendGrid is able to do something that we cannot. I have setup my server with https and a letsencrypt certificate. I am gonna take up the challenge and make it work without sendgrid! Haha! I shall get back to you once I have some progress :P

Comment: I'm back! And with a solution!!! Well, this probably might not have been the issue for you but for me, as it turns out, my mail ports were blocked. So sendgrid seems to work because it's sending a http request to sendgrid APIs through port 80 (more likely to be 443) so sendgrid didn't have an issue. But my own mails weren't going through because my server host (digital ocean) had apparently blocked all my mail ports. I wouldn't mind them doing that but I never knew about this at all. Informing me would've saved a lot of time. Digital ocean, if you're reading this: not cool man, not cool.

Comment: Andrew, just for the sake of curiosity, could you check if your ports are blocked and let me know if your mail solution also works once they're unblocked? It's not necessary, but for the sake of quenching my own curiosity and inquisitiveness, could you let me know if it works for you once the ports are unblocked? If that's not an issue, of course. I'm merely curious that's all.

Comment: Hi @RakshithRavi switch the port to 2525. From the comment made here https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/port-465-587-25-on-my-droplet-is-blocked-cannot-send-email-to-my-custumer-please-help-me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. But it turned out that on the virtual server, the provider blocked the outgoing port 587 by default. I contacted the virtual server support, they unblocked the port and everything worked.